# ExtJS Combobox Array

Tags: arrays, extjs, combobox, default-value

I want to create a combobox with the following array:

```
var operators = new Array(">=",">","=~","","!=","=","<","<=");
```

The issue is that I would like the first element (and sometimes the last element) to be the default value of the comboxbox. I could not find how to successfully do this.

Thanks so much and sorry if duplicate.

**EDIT**

```
var ops = new Array(">=",">","=~","","!=","=","<","<=");
var operators = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({ id: 0, fields: [ 'value' ], data: ops });

Ext.getCmp('variablesAttributesPanel').add({xtype: 'combo',     id: variables[j].getTitle() + 'MinCombo', mode: 'local', valueField: 'value', displayField: 'value', store: operators,  width: 50,  x: 240, y: (j * 20 + 19), editable: false, allowBlank: false});
```

This is making the options in the dropdown list >, =, , !, <

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure triggerAction is set in combo box config

`triggerAction : 'all'`

```
var operators = new Array(">=",">","=~","x","!=","=","<","<=");

var test1 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    height:100,
    width:100,
    store: operators
});

var test2 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    height:100,
    width:100,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    store: operators
});

var win=new Ext.Window({
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    items:[test1,test2],
    height:300,
    width:300,
    title:'comboWin'
}).show();

test1.setValue(operators[1]);
test2.setValue(operators[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the setValue method of the combobox.  In this case, the display and value are the same so you can just pass in the array value:

```
comboBox.setValue(operators[0]);
```

Comment: It seems when I do that, the operators[0] is the only one in the list.

Comment: In your declaration of the combobox, you must specify the array as the 'data' element of the store:

var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  xtype: 'combo',
  mode: 'local',
  store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        id: 0,
        fields: [
            'value'
        ],
        data: operators
    }),
    valueField: 'value',
    displayField: 'value'
});

Comment: you need to initialize the store as an ArrayStore like I have in my comment.